# Mirroring Mocap Character Animation (Skeletal .bvh)

Tags: python, animation, quaternions

I'm trying to mirror the CMU motion capture dataset(.bvh format)
along world-yz plane with python code.

I already parsed them and converted the euler angles representation to quaternion representation.

I found some answers for the mirrorin by negating y and z components.
qx qy qz qw -> qx -qy -qz qw

However, this does not seem to work for all joints for skeletal animation.

I checked the mirroring above works for a single object rotation in unity3d engine.

The step I used for mirroring is same as below,
1. exchange left-joint local rotations and right-joint local rotations
2. negate qy and qz for all joint rotations
3. negate x of root trajectory

```py
def mirror_sequence(sequence):
    mirrored_rotations = sequence[:, 1:, :]
    mirrored_trajectory = np.expand_dims(sequence[:, 0, :], axis=1)

    temp = mirrored_rotations

    # Flip left/right joints
    mirrored_rotations[:, joints_left] = temp[:, joints_right]
    mirrored_rotations[:, joints_right] = temp[:, joints_left]

    mirrored_rotations[:, :, [1, 2]] *= -1  
    mirrored_trajectory[:, :, 0] *= -1

    mirrored_sequence = np.concatenate((mirrored_trajectory, mirrored_rotations), axis=1)

    return mirrored_sequence
```

My goal is to make an animation which has pelvis trajectory mirrored along world-yz plane and left / right joint animation swapped.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was so simple...

temp = mirrored_rotations

I use to code in C# and thought and dealing with temp would not change

values in mirrored_rotations...

temp = mirrored_rotations.copy() works well.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a bit overkill, but I had this issue recently and it was non-trivial for me to solve, even using the above method. For others looking at this, a great mocap library that can do this is [PyMo](https://github.com/omimo/PyMO).

Wtih this library you can mirror over a particular axis (in this case, X) as well as do other fun things:

```
from pymo.parsers import BVHParser
from pymo.writers import BVHWriter
from pymo.preprocessing import *

p = BVHParser()
dat = []
for f in bvh_files:
    data_all.append(p.parse(f))
data_pipe = Pipeline([
   ('dwnsampl', DownSampler(tgt_fps=fps,  keep_all=False)),
   ('root', RootTransformer('hip_centric')),
   ('mir', Mirror(axis='X', append=False)),      # <-- the relevant line
   ('jtsel', JointSelector(['Spine','Spine1','Spine2','Spine3','Neck','Neck1','Head','RightShoulder', 'RightArm', 'RightForeArm', 'RightHand', 'LeftShoulder', 'LeftArm', 'LeftForeArm', 'LeftHand'], include_root=True)),
   ('exp', MocapParameterizer('expmap')),
   ('cnst', ConstantsRemover()),
   ('np', Numpyfier())
])

out_data = data_pipe.fit_transform(data_all)


# and then to write your transformed files out: 
inv_data = data_pipeline.inverse_transform(out_data)
writer = BVHWriter()
for i in range(0, out_data.shape[0]):
    with open(bvh_files[i], "w") as f:
        writer.write(inv_data[i], f, framerate=fps)
```

Be wary that the library changes often, but even as it changes the bare bones to do many useful transformations on bvh data is there and very solid.

Comment: Do you know where the `Mirror` class should be located? I've looked inside the PyMO repository here https://github.com/omimo/PyMO but didn't find the Mirror transformation in the current state of the repo (I'm not completely sure about previous versions, but I haven't found it there either). Also, I guess `Pipeline` should be imported from `sklearn.pipeline` am I right?